# Apache Ignite Web Console on Google Kubernetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ignite

Has anyone tried installing Apache Ignite Web Console on Google Kubernetes Engine? Do you have the steps to do it?

Comment: did you try https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/ignite ?

Comment: That helm chart is for Ignite cluster nodes, not Web Console.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a few resources which may help you.

1. [Instruction](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/kubernetes-installation) on how to install Apache Ignite Web Console in Kubernetes.
2. [Instruction](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/deploying-web-console-kubernetes) on how to install GridGain Web Console in Kubernetes (generic). GridGain Web Console is compatible with Apache Ignite clusters. It is similar to Apache Ignite Web Console but adds a few more features.
3. A free public GridGain Web Console [deployment](https://console.gridgain.com).

I'd suggest to try the latter option first so that you can start using the tool without allocating any resources or bothering with installation.